# python flask alert on html while running a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, alert

I am currently using flask as the back end of my web page navigator, and can run a thread on a post method. The thread is basically a counting class function that is in another python file(counter.py), I'm looking for a way to alert the user from the front end when the thread has done counting by 5. Is there another tool or library that I need to use for this? I'm not that good at web programming so any tips would really help. Thanks! :)

```
    class count(threading.Thread)

        def __init__(self): 
            count = 0

        def run(self):
            while count < 20:
            print count 
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1
            if count % 5 == 0:
                #alert user
                pass
```

here is my code for my flask

```
    import flask, flask.views
    import counter

    myThread = counter.count()

    app = flask.Flask(__name__)

    class View(flask.views.MethodView):

        def get(self):
            return flask.render_template('index.html', message=l.message)

        def post(self):
            myThread.start()
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('main'))

    app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=View.as_view('main'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])

    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

And my index.html.
Basically just a button, I'll add more pages in the future

```
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Execute" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: you need to use websockets afaik ... or repeatedly call a url that reports if the job is done ... beware with threading and webapplications they dont always work how you would expect... can you just fake it (ie a timer on the client side in javascript)? what is the purpose of this exercise?